# How to download an iOS Developer Enterprise Program Applications via URL?

Tags: ios

I want to download an iOS Developer Enterprise Program Applications via URL. Now I have host the plist and ipa file in my server.  And plist file is a https link, link can open with Browser, ipa also can download via link in plist file. But when I connect itms URL like  `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://xxxxxxxxxx.plist`, it shows that `"Cannot connect to xxxxx"`. How can I fix that? Thx.

Comment: This may be caused by your server or your manifest. Please check that your server SSL certificate is valid and try to access the plist file in your browser for sure that you can access it and without authentication. If your server work perfectly then check your manifest file.

Comment: I can access the plist file browser.   But I  cannot find problem any more~  could you help me ~~  my link "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://git.oschina.net/lx614happy/appRadar/blob/master/appRadar.plist"

Comment: add "https://" before "git"   and   add "appRadar.plist"  after   "master/"

Comment: Your host of your plist file is not work like download file when open URL. 
I uploaded your plist file to dropbox and it work perfectly. Try this "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57764645/appRadar.plist"

Comment: If you finish test please tell me and i'll remove it from my dropbox.

Comment: Thx~ It's really work well. I'll check is there anything wrong on our server.

Comment: Your server should return the file as it's type but now it return as html to view the file contents. And please tell me when you want me to remove your manifest.plist from my dropbox account.

Comment: I have fixed this problem, Thx~~ you can remove my manifest.plist from you dropbox account~